# Callback of Moq is not called?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

In the following code. The `Assert.Equal(...)` of the `Callback()` is never called?

```
var test = "Test";

var command = new MyCommand { V = test };

var mock = new Mock<IRepository>(); // IRepository has the method of Save()
var p = new P(test);
mock.Setup(x => x.Save(p))
    .Callback<P>(x => Assert.Equal(x.Value, test)); // break point on Assert.Equal not hit

var sut = new C(mock.Object);
var result = await sut.M(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```cs
.Setup(x => x.Save(p))
```

but are you sure the `P` used in your SUT is "equal to" just that `p`? Instead you could do:

```cs
.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<P>()))
```

and in that case the set-up (and call-back) would apply to any argument.

Comment: But I will not be able to compare the values in the `Assert()` if using `It.IsAny<P>())`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 You should be able to use `Callback` even if you use `It.IsAny<P>`.  The idea is that you don't care what `P` is sent to `Save`, but you want to test it.  What happens when you use `It.IsAny<P>` and `Callback`?  You can also put `.Verifiable()` after the `Callback`.

Comment: This is not a good solution. If you have the same call multiple times you want to callback on a certain one, you don't want to use IsAny because it will conflict.